# flutter - firebase orderby first added first

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase data

[image]

When reading from database, last added node becomes first(reverse order).

Database reference:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('learn/all');
```

and StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: databaseReference .onValue,
builder: (context, snap) {

    if (snap.hasData && !snap.hasError && snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {

        Map data = snap.data.snapshot.value;
        List item = [];

        data.forEach((index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));

        return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: item.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(item[index]['question']),
                );
                },
            );
    }
    else
        return Text("No data");
    },
)
```

How to retrieve in a order of first added first?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of an object that exists under `all` node.

Comment: @AlexMamo there is one child called id on each node.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ashique Valanchery your question isn't complete if you want to reverse your list you must use `descending` in your `orderBy` method

```
final fireStore = Firestore.instance;

var temp = fireStore.collection("collectionPath").orderBy("field", descending: true);
```

And for Realtime Database you must reverse your data locally because Realtime Database doesn't have any way to reverse your data, like the bellow code:

```
var temp = {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2};

var sortedKeys = temp.keys.toList(growable: true)
  ..sort((k1, k2) =>
      temp[k1].compareTo(temp[k2]));
LinkedHashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap.fromIterable(sortedKeys,
    key: (k) => k, value: (k) => temp[k]);
print("Mahdi: sort editContactListener: $sortedMap");
```

Comment: Sorry, not firestore, it is firebase realtime db. There are many articles found for firestore like you answered. But in case of firebase database, I can't find anything.

Comment: OP is looking for a solution for Firebase Realtime Database, and not for Cloud Firestore. While both are apart of Firebase, both are two different products, with two different mechanisms.

Comment: Ashique Valanchery did you get your answer?

Comment: @abbasjafary no, there is one parameter for ListView for reversing. But not working as expected. If there is any firebase method for ordering, that will be good. For flutter, I can't find a solution.

Comment: As I said Realtime Database doesn't have any method for reverse a list, and for this reason first you must order your list from Realtime Database, and after that, you must reverse your list locally or programmatically.